# Setting up proxy for HTTP client

Tags: http, proxy, request, go

I'm trying to setup the HTTP client so that it uses a proxy, however I cannot quite understand how to do it. The documentation has multiple reference to "proxy" but none of the functions seem to allow to define the proxy. What I need is something like this:

```
client := &http.Client{}
client.SetProxy("someip:someport") // pseudo code
resp, err := client.Get("http://example.com") // do request through proxy
```

Any idea how to do this in Go?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

lukad is correct, you could set the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable, if you do this Go will use it by default.

Bash:

```
export HTTP_PROXY="http://proxyIp:proxyPort"
```

Go:

```
os.Setenv("HTTP_PROXY", "http://proxyIp:proxyPort")
```

You could also construct your own http.Client that MUST use a proxy regardless of the environment's configuration:

```
proxyUrl, err := url.Parse("http://proxyIp:proxyPort")
myClient := &http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl)}}
```

This is useful if you can not depend on the environment's configuration, or do not want to modify it.

You could also modify the default transport used by the "`net/http`" package. This would affect your entire program (including the default HTTP client).

```
proxyUrl, err := url.Parse("http://proxyIp:proxyPort")
http.DefaultTransport = &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl)}
```

Comment: In fact, I need to concurrently send several requests, each using a different proxy, so your second solution is probably what I need. However, it doesn't seem to be working, I'm getting this error for all the proxies: `Get http://stackoverflow.com: http: error connecting to proxy 87.236.233.92:8080: GetServByName: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.` Any idea what it means?

Comment: I got my answer to this question there - http://stackoverflow.com/q/14669958/561309

Comment: @voidlogic setting the env variable didn't work for me. I have to pass it to the http.Transport

Comment: Would this also be possible with a socks5 proxy?

Comment: If your proxy requires an username and password along with IP, the `export HTTP_PROXY="http://proxyIp:proxyPort"` becomes `export HTTP_PROXY="http://PROXY_LOGIN:PROXY_PASS@proxyIp:proxyPort"`

Comment: If you are requesting an HTTPS address, you should also add HTTPS_PROXY environment variable

Answer (score 17):

Go will use the the proxy defined in the environment variable `HTTP_PROXY` if it's set. Otherwise it will use no proxy.

You could do it like this:

```
os.Setenv("HTTP_PROXY", "http://someip:someport")
resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: FYI -- the `return` after the `panic` [is redundant](http://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover).

Answer (score 8):

May you could also try this:

```
url_i := url.URL{}
url_proxy, _ := url_i.Parse(proxy_addr)

transport := http.Transport{}    
transport.Proxy = http.ProxyURL(url_proxy)// set proxy 
transport.TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true} //set ssl

client := &http.Client{}
client.Transport = transport
resp, err := client.Get("http://example.com") // do request through proxy
```

Comment: I think you mean: transport := &http.Transport{}

Comment: make sure you actually want `InsecureSkipVerify` before you paste this in to your code

Comment: hint: you don't want InsecureSkipVerify

Answer (score 3):

The Go built-in proxy use is briefly documented in the `DefaultTransport`:

```
// DefaultTransport .... It uses HTTP proxies
// as directed by the $HTTP_PROXY and $NO_PROXY (or $http_proxy and
// $no_proxy) environment variables.
var DefaultTransport RoundTripper = &Transport{
    Proxy: ProxyFromEnvironment,
```

This points to the usefulness of creating custom Transports from `DefaultTransport` vs. from scratch to take advantage of the built-in `ProxyFromEnvironment` function

Answer (score 1):

If you run something like this:

```
HTTP_PROXY=89.x.y.z path_to_program
```

Then the HTTP_PROXY setting is set for that command only, which is useful if you don't want to set it for the whole shell session.
Note: there's no ; between the setting and the path; if you put a semicolon, it would set (but not export) HTTP_PROXY  for that shell

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative way, you can also use [GoRequest](https://github.com/parnurzeal/gorequest) which has a feature that you can set proxy easily for any single request.

```
request := gorequest.New()
resp, body, errs:= request.Proxy("http://proxy:999").Get("http://example.com").End()
resp2, body2, errs2 := request.Proxy("http://proxy2:999").Get("http://example2.com").End()
```

Or you can set for the whole at once.

```
request := gorequest.New().Proxy("http://proxy:999")
resp, body, errs:= request.Get("http://example.com").End()
resp2, body2, errs2 := request.Get("http://example2.com").End()
```

Comment: gorequest does not support socks proxies