# How to get a web server to send outbound http requests through local fiddler proxy?

Tags: proxy, fiddler, network-traffic

I'm running a local web server written in Go and I can debug traffic going to it from my browser; but, I can't see the http request that it makes to external services.

Do I have to run some particular configuration of the web server in order to get the traffic to appear in fiddler? It is running as a background process.

Comment: added a reference to [GoProxy](https://github.com/elazarl/goproxy) in my answer if you really want to build in proxy connections into your web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **you can't**...

...*unless* your web application is written to open a connection to a Proxy server and route requests through that connection (e.g. connect to a remote proxy, and then send requests through it).

Typically what developers do is just dump the Web Request/Response to a debug file to inspect during development (or to debug on a live server, by enabling it with a flag at runtime).

**Fiddler** is a "proxy" service/server.  When you are using it normally to debug browser requests, your *Browser* is configured to connect to a *Proxy* server.  That is, it will send all web requests through your fiddler's local server (I think it's localhost:8888 if i remember from my Windows days of using Fiddler) which in turn makes a connection to your local web server that you are debugging.

[You can read more about Proxies at Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server)

[image: proxy server]

In that picture above, your local web server would be *Alice*.  Meaning, Alice would need to be configured to connect to a proxy server and then make web requests through it.

EDIT:

(for the "I really need this" crowd)

If you really want to modify your web server to send requests through a proxy, there are a few Go packages already written to help you.  [GoProxy](https://github.com/elazarl/goproxy) is one such package.

Comment: @thurt the answer is correct for what the OP asked.  and the answer and link you provided I think is way off.  the OP wants to see the requests his service makes outbound to the internet.  The answer you linked to talks about setting up a proxy for `go get` commands.  Those are two very different things.

Comment: thanks, you're right about the comment I posted. I removed that comment and here is a better answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14663620/3072751 -- this does route outbound http traffic to the proxy.

the http_proxy convention is discussed here https://superuser.com/questions/944958/are-http-proxy-https-proxy-and-no-proxy-environment-variables-standard