# How do I record REST API calls with Charles Web Proxy?

Tags: rest, go, proxy, julia, charles-proxy

I am using Charles Web Debugging Proxy to debug REST API calls to DeviantArt (https://www.deviantart.com). When I am recording I can see various other calls happing in the background from my Web Browser. But the calls I make from my Julia (and Golang) application doesn't show up. Just blank. Even if I put the Deviant ART endpoint in specifically as the include for record settings it makes no difference.

I assume I must get my Julia app to somehow use Charles. Or maybe not? I don't know how this works.

Comment: Guessing: you're looking for a configuration setting, somewhere, that instructs the HTTP client running in your Julia app to use an HTTP proxy, and you'll want to specify values for that setting that point to the port being used by Charles.  Maybe this starting point helps?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14663620/54734